# Symfony 2 Must Implement UserProviderInterface

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, repository, entity

I get this error 'Must implement UserProviderInterface' 
when trying to using the symfony login features.  I'm referencing the repository * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Login\LogBundle\Entity\Repository\UserRepository") . Does anyone have any ideas.

Entity

```
  <?php
  namespace Login\LogBundle\Entity;

  use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
  use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
  /**
  * @ORM\Table(name="user")
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Login\LogBundle\Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
  * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
  */
 class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
 {
/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $username;

  /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
 */
private $salt;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
 */
private $isActive;

 /**
  /**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="userapidetails", mappedBy="user")
 */
public $userapidetails;

 public function __construct()
{
    $this->userapidetails = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->isActive = true;
    $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
}

public function getUserapidetails() {
   return $this->userapidetails;
}

// public function setUserapidetails($userapidetails) {
//    $this->userapi=$userapidetails;

//    return $this;
// }
/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 * @return User
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get password
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return User
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set username
 *
 * @param string $username
 * @return User
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get username
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $isactive;


/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 * @return User
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Set salt
 *
 * @param string $salt
 * @return User
 */
public function setSalt($salt)
{
    $this->salt = $salt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get salt
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSalt()
{
    return $this->salt;
}

/**
 * Set isactive
 *
 * @param string $isactive
 * @return User
 */
public function setIsactive($isactive)
{
    $this->isactive = $isactive;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get isactive
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getIsactive()
{
    return $this->isactive;
}




 /**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return array('ROLE_USER');
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function eraseCredentials()
{
}

/**
 * @see \Serializable::serialize()
 */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->salt,
        $this->password,
    ));
}

/**
 * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
 */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->salt,
        $this->password,
    ) = unserialize($serialized);
  }







  }
```

Repository

```
      // src/Acme/UserBundle/Entity/UserRepository.php
    namespace Login\LogBundle\Entity;

   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
   use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
   use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
   use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
   use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
   use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;

  class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
  {
  public function loadUserByUsername($username)
  {
    $q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
        ->setParameter('username', $username)
        ->setParameter('email', $username)
        ->getQuery();

    try {
        // The Query::getSingleResult() method throws an exception
        // if there is no record matching the criteria.
        $user = $q->getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException $e) {
        $message = sprintf(
 'Unable to find an active admin AcmeUserBundle:User object identified    by    "%s".',
            $username
        );
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message, 0, $e);
    }

    return $user;
}

public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    $class = get_class($user);
    if (!$this->supportsClass($class)) {
        throw new UnsupportedUserException(
            sprintf(
                'Instances of "%s" are not supported.',
                $class
            )
        );
    }

    return $this->find($user->getId());
}

public function supportsClass($class)
{
    return $this->getEntityName() === $class
        || is_subclass_of($class, $this->getEntityName());
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the app/config/security.yml file with something like this:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    providers:
        main:
            entity:
                class: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
                property: username
```

And path to repositoryClass `UserRepository` is wrong, maybe you mean this:

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Login\LogBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
```

becouse you use namespace `\Login\LogBundle\Entity\UserRepository`.

Comment: Fix the `UserRepository` namespace in `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Login\LogBundle\Entity\Repository\UserRepository")` to `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Login\LogBundle\Entity\UserRepository")`

Comment: Is this fix your problem?

Comment: yes thanks, this is how they recommend providers:
        main:
            entity: { class: LoginLogBundle:User ,property: username}

Answer (score 2):

To load user from Repository, you should omit the { property: username } from security.yml.

Comment: it is necessary in symfony >2.3 but not in symfony <2.2