# Symfony2. Security login on a joined table

Tags: security, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to make a login functionality using the ServiceBundle in Symfony2. The question is: is there a way to use the Entity "Profile" with unique field uid if this is connected to a "Students" Entity on a OneToOne relation ?

So far i just get the error:

"ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Proxies__CG__\Acme\StudentsManagerBundle\Entity\Student could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony.localhost\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AbstractAuthenticationListener.php line 215"

Here is the Doctrine code

```
...
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\StudentsManagerBundle\Entity\Student")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cnp", referencedColumnName="cnp")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ActivareCont", mappedBy="cnp")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $cnp;
...
```

Thanks

Comment: You cannot make one related field be related to another entity; You need to create a separate field for each one. [http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional]

Comment: I can't make this way. The exact scenario is this one: Students, Profiles and CheckProfiles (this one has the verification codes for each profile). I want all these 3 tabels have the same primary key - the unique identifier in my country (cnp).

Comment: I appreciate your point of view. Can you tell me what should i do if i have just one join Student-Profile (OneToOne). I need the login use the cnp from Profile and Profile needs the cnp be already in the Students table. I just want to make a login for the a profile. The only issue is that this tabel is connected to Students.

Comment: "*I want all these 3 tables have the same primary key*" what do you mean by that? If you make one table as main and its primary key be used in other two tables as foreign key the join will be established; to do your authentication, you need to create a custom DB user provider and create a join query to find the user (by any property if you want) then do the same for custom authentication provider. I can give you these links to create your providers [http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#authenticating-someone-with-a-custom-entity-provider]

Comment: And this link to create a custom authentication provider [http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html]

Comment: I have tried last 9 hours using your first link. The second one is to complex for me and i don't think i can handle. Still i found using UserProviderInterface might help. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185642/symfony-2-must-implement-userproviderinterface . I can't try right now, i really need a brake but if you have more experience with symfony tell me please if this approach makes sense for you.

Comment: I know it seems complicated; but I think the only thing you need (after creating the entities correctly) is to create a correct DQL query in `loadUserByUsername` so that you be able to find user base on your criteria